# See what objects are hogging the most memory in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, mobile

How can I list objects allocated/alive in my iOS app sorted by memory usage (greatest to least)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profile using Xcode's *[Allocation Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html):*

[image: allocations instruments]

Statistics information in the Detail pane shows:

- **Live Bytes**: The number of bytes that have been allocated, but not released.
- **Living**: The number of objects created and still on the heap.
- **Transitory**: The number of objects that were created and destroyed in the selected time range.
- **Overall Bytes**: The total number of bytes of this type that have been allocated, including those that have been released.
- **Overall**: The total number of objects or memory blocks of this type that have been allocated, including those that have been released.
- **Allocations (Net / Overall)**: A histogram of the current and total accounts.

Comment: Is there anyway to see what objects are using the most memory? Like, NSString containing the text "Hello, World!" is using 100 bytes or something like that.